# what's wrong in my C program?

Tags: c

a cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
#include "Hello.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

typedef void(__stdcall *Print_)();

int main(){

  HINSTANCE hDll;   //DLL句柄 
  Print_ print_;  //函数指针
  hDll = LoadLibrary("Hello.dll");

  if (hDll != NULL)
   { 

    print_ = (Print_)GetProcAddress(hDll,"Java_Hello_sayHello@8"); 
    if(print_!=NULL)
    {

     print_();
    } 
    FreeLibrary(hDll); 
   }
 return 0;

}
```

//there is something wrong, it prints:
http://i983.photobucket.com/albums/ae311/keatingWang/c_wrong.png
未声明的标识符 means : Undeclared identifier

Comment: You're more likely to get help searching by the error number (C, then a bunch of numbers) then the actual message, espically if it's not in English.

Comment: Please update the image if you have changed the code

Comment: You'll do us and yourself a favour if you'll stick to the 32-127 subset of ASCII in your source code (read: stick to English). This is the language programmers communicate in, as much as it sucks for people like you and me who'd prefer a different language.

Comment: Is this C or C++ ?  You include <iostream> but you have this tagged as C

Comment: @wilhelmtell "stick to the 32-127 subset of ASCII in your source code" --> hope you do not mind code 10 in source code.

Answer (score 10):

Consider the macro:

```
#define HINSTANCE "hDll"
```

and its use:

```
HINSTANCE hDll;   //DLL句柄
```

after preprocessing it would look like:

```
"hDll" hDll;
```

which clearly is an error as it makes `hDll` undeclared as `"hDll"` is not a valid type.

Comment: delete #define HINSTANCE "hDll"
there still is something wrong

Answer (score 2):

remove

```
#define HINSTANCE "hDLL"
```

To remove C4627 warning, move up `#include "stdafx.h"` to the top (to be the first #include) as indicated by [Mike Dinsdale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187599/mike-dinsdale)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627112/whats-wrong-in-my-c-program/2627304#2627304). This will probably solve error for `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress`, and `FreeLibrary`:

```
#include "stdafx.h" // moved up
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
#include "Hello.h"
#include "windows.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a pre-compiled header issue?  With some project settings VC++ will skip stuff before the `#include "stdafx.h"`, which I think might be the cause of the C4627 warnings you're getting.  Have you tried moving `#include "stdafx.h"` before your other `#include`s?